# C array to Rcpp NumericVector

Tags: c, arrays, r, rcpp

I am working with C arrays, and I need to convert them to `Rcpp::NumericVector` at some point in my code. I tried the following code but it throws an error (cannot convert from double [5] to type 'SEXP'). What is the right way to convert from a C array to `NumericVector`?

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
'
NumericVector fun() {
  double data[5] = {1.0, 2.0. 1.0, 2.0, 1.0};
  return as<NumericVector>(data);
}
')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of two ways this can be done:

**1: range constructor**

```
cppFunction('
    NumericVector fun() {
        double data[5] = {1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,1.0};
        return NumericVector(data,data+sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data));
    }
');
fun();
## [1] 1 2 1 2 1
```

**2: build an STL vector, wrap in an SEXP, and finally wrap in `NumericVector`**

```
cppFunction('
    NumericVector fun() {
        double data[5] = {1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,1.0};
        return as<NumericVector>(wrap(std::vector<double>(data,data+sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data))));
    }
');
fun();
## [1] 1 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: Form 1 is preferred. Iterator-alike reference to the beginning of content plus its extent.  That has all been documented since the very beginning too.  If I tried hard enough I am sure I could find earlier post here too...